# Changing date formats in R

Tags: r, date

I am working on a script in R

Currently my dates are formated as int and are in this format "%Y%m%d" i.e. 20200124

How do i change them to 24012020? How do i change them to 2020-01-24?

Comment: You can use `format` i..e `format(as.Date('20200124', '%Y%m%d'), '%d%m%Y')`  the second format is already the default format from `as.Date` output

Comment: `format(as.Date('20200124', '%Y%m%d'), '%Y-%m-%d")`